# monitoring an exe application launching

Tags: perl, poe

I need to monitor an console exe application which don't have any stdin from the user it only print some info  to the screen i used a POE:Wheel for this task

Below are my code:

```
use POE qw( Wheel::Run);

    POE::Session->create(
      inline_states => {
         _start => sub {
            my ($heap) = $_[HEAP];

            my $run    = POE::Wheel::Run->new(
                Program      => "my_program.exe",
                StdoutEvent  => "print"
            );


            $heap->{run}  = $run   ;

         },

         print => sub {print "somthing";}
      }
    );
$poe_kernel->run(  );
```

When i run the above code/script and  run the my_program.exe i didn't see any print on the screen
could someone tell what could be my problem here .

Answer (score 1):

> What could be my problem here

Three likely candidates as far as I see:

1. `my_program.exe` ran but produced no output
2. `my_program.exe` could not be executed
    The program is not in the path, has the wrong permissions, isn't an executable, etc.
    A `StderrEvent` is perhaps the easiest way to catch this, as the child process will `warn()` about the failure to `exec()`.
3. Your output is line buffered
   The `"print"` state handler emits output without a newline, which might not appear until perl's termination when output buffers are flushed.  Your script won't terminate, however, until the `{run}` wheel is removed from the session's `HEAP`, which you can (and should) do in a `sig_child` handler.